# Session handling in JQuery and node.js

Tags: jquery, session, node.js, express

I am trying to use session with expressjs and jquery.

I have a node.js server @127.0.0.1:6060 with this code :

```
var Express = require('express'),
  App = Express.createServer(),
  Mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = Mongoose.Schema,
  ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

App.configure(function () {
  App.use(Express.bodyParser());
  App.use(Express.methodOverride());
  App.use(Express.logger({ format: '[:remote-addr] :method :url :response-time ms' }));

  App.use(Express.cookieParser());
  App.use(Express.session({ secret: "keyboard cat" }));

  // CORS
  App.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS,GET,POST,PUT,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With');

    next(); 
  });
});

App.all('/api/users/test1', function (req, res) {
  req.session.test = 'toto';
  console.log(req.session.id)
  res.send({'r': req.session.id});
});
App.all('/api/users/test2', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.session.id)
  res.send({'r': req.session.test});
});

App.listen(6060, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('App launched ...');
```

Ok, now if I directly enter http://127.0.0.1:6060/api/users/test1 then http://127.0.0.1:6060/api/users/test2 in my browser, I get my object result with 'toto'.

However, if I try with jquery 1.7.1 :

```
$.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:6060/api/users/test1', function (json) {
    console.log(json.result);
    $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:6060/api/users/test2', function (json) {
        console.log(json.result)
    });
});
```

I get an empty js object in the last print.
I really do not understand. Any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explications

`$.getJSON` call to Express to create a new session because your link is absolute (*http://...*), you need to call your server with a relative link (*/api/users/test1* for exemple).

### Solution

You need to have your application on the same server and port **or** use an API key to recognize the user.

### Code

I'll use the first solution, to have the application on the same server and port.
On the server, you just need to specify to Express that you use a static directory like this in your `App.configure` :

```
App.use(Express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));
```

In your **public/** folder, put your **index.html** which contains :

```
$.get('/api/users/test1', function (json) {
    // display something like "74V5zXFyOe0KYKG8somXUzoR.maraL4zDfFfyLfEU4W/i8eioMMK5f4+YOnUVeJO8abU"
    console.log(json.r);
    $.getJSON('/api/users/test2', function (json) {
        // display : 'toto'
        console.log(json.r)
    });
});
```

**Go on http://localhost:6060/ and look the console.**

Comment: Oh I thought port was not important ! Thanks a lot it solved my problem !

Comment: You welcome! You can have a glance to the [same origin policy on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules).